# Get clipboard history in openSUSE Tumbleweed or Leap 42.1

Tags: kde, clipboard

I am looking to access items (text) I have previously copied to the clipboard in KDE (openSUSE). I haven't restarted the system since the items were copied.

Is there any way of accessing the clipboard history on this operating system? Also, if anyone knows ways that work on other distributions you're welcome to pop them down as an answer, as I am sure they are worth a try.

Update: When attempting to use `klipper` I get the following error:

```
QSystemTrayIcon::setVisible: No Icon set
Couldn't start kglobalaccel from org.kde.kglobalaccel.service: QDBusError("org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildSignaled", "Process org.kde.kglobalaccel received signal 6")
Failed to connect to the kglobalaccel daemon QDBusError("org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner", "Could not get owner of name 'org.kde.kglobalaccel': no such name")
log_klipper: Failed to load history resource. Clipboard history cannot be read. :  History file does not exist
Failed to connect to the kglobalaccel daemon QDBusError("org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner", "Could not get owner of name 'org.kde.kglobalaccel': no such name")
Failed to connect to the kglobalaccel daemon QDBusError("org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner", "Could not get owner of name 'org.kde.kglobalaccel': no such name")
Failed to connect to the kglobalaccel daemon QDBusError("org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner", "Could not get owner of name 'org.kde.kglobalaccel': no such name")
Failed to connect to the kglobalaccel daemon QDBusError("org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner", "Could not get owner of name 'org.kde.kglobalaccel': no such name")
Failed to connect to the kglobalaccel daemon QDBusError("org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner", "Could not get owner of name 'org.kde.kglobalaccel': no such name")
Failed to connect to the kglobalaccel daemon QDBusError("org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner", "Could not get owner of name 'org.kde.kglobalaccel': no such name")
QSystemTrayIcon::setVisible: No Icon set
```

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing but it might, just might, depend on your graphical environment. Which one are you using? In the future, I suggest you install one of the many clipboard helper tools that do provide this functionality. That won't help you now though, only the next time.

Comment: I just know you can do it in Windows is all, but I guess Windows might have a background process running recording a set number of clipboard copies to a buffer. I'm on KDE.

Comment: Hang on, it might, I haven't used KDE in years. Do you have `klipper` installed? Have a look at https://www.maketecheasier.com/use-kde-clipboard-and-klipper-app/. If that works for you, please either post an answer or let me know and I'll post one, so the question can be marked as answered.

Comment: Yup, I have ```klipper```. Updated with additional info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found `klipper` history folder in `~/.local/share/klipper`. Running `cat` on `history2.lst` file outputs the clipboard history since last restart of the server instance (had to run `rcxdm`). Couldn't find the supplementary information I was looking for as `history1.lst/history.lst` (I assume there should be a first file if there is a second...) was absent from the directory, but I appear to have answered my own question as originally asked.

Update: a recent update to openSUSE Tumbleweed also seems to have added a clipboard icon to the taskbar, which makes it easy to see your clipboard history.